# JQuery draggable droppable

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm using jquery's plugin for dragging and dropping image to a div. The dragging works, but the dropping is not.

The images are displayed from java script after an ajax call. Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: urlBase + "/api/services/getserviceitems?servicetype=0",
                context: document.body,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var html = "<table><tr>";
                var ctr = 0;
                $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                    if (ctr < 3) {
                        html += "<td class='item'><img src='" + urlBase + "/file/getimage/" + v.FileId + "' style='width:120px; height:120px; padding:5px'><div style='font-size:12px; margin-left:5px; margin-top:-5px;'>$" + v.Price + ".00</div></td>"
                        ctr++;
                    }
                    else {
                        ctr = 0;
                        html += "<tr><td class='item' ><img class='item' src='" + urlBase + "/file/getimage/" + v.FileId + "' style='width:120px; height:120px; padding:5px'><div style='font-size:12px; margin-left:5px; margin-top:-5px;'>$" + v.Price + ".00</div></td></tr>"
                        ctr++;
                    }
                html += "</tr></table>";
                $('#menuTabContent').html(html);

                });
                enableDragDrop()
```

This is my code for my drag and drop.

```
function enableDragDrop() {
            $('.item').draggable({
                revert: true,
                proxy: 'clone',
                onStartDrag: function () {
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index', 10);
                },
                onStopDrag: function () {
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'move';
                }
            });

            $('.newRequestModalBody-Right').droppable({
                onDragEnter: function (e, source) {
                    alert("!!!!");
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'auto';
                },
                onDragLeave: function (e, source) {
                    alert("!!!!");
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop: function (e, source) {
                    //var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    //var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                    //addItem(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
                    alert("!!!!");
                }
            });
        }
```

The div that is set in the droppable was created normally.

```
<div id ="requestDv"></div>
```

I'm creating a table for the requestDv in JS:

```
 function loadGuestRequestItems(){
        var html = "";

        html = "<p style='padding:10px;font-size:12px;'>Requests(Drag items here)</p>"
        html += "<table style='font-size:12px;' class='table table-striped'>";
        html += "   <tr>";
        html += "       <th>Type</th>";
        html += "       <th>Details</th>";
        html += "   </tr>";
        html += "</table>";

        $('#requestDv').html(html);
    }
```

Another thing, the proxy: 'clone' doesn't work. The whole image is still being drag removing the image from its place. Thank you in advance!

Comment: jsfiddle will be great

Comment: I can't since I'm loading the image from an API

Comment: `.newRequestModalBody-Right` is `table` or what? You create `<div id ="requestDv"></div>` for dropping but it has not droppable event? (im bit confuse)

Comment: Also you join strings to html ... but I dont see any `.append` or `.html`. And you dont have to call `enableDragDrop()` each time ... just call it after `.each`

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my post. Regarding your question about the div not having a droppable event. I just followed what this link says. http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd2.php

Answer (score 0):

> Another thing, the proxy: 'clone' doesn't work.

it should be helper:"clone" [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper)

```
revert: true
```

From jQuery doc:

> Boolean: If set to true the element will always revert.

So you want:

`revert:"invalid"`

Here is a simple example  : http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/8BY5e/